# SlowCheetah Azure web role not transformed

Tags: azure, msbuild, slowcheetah

I am using SlowCheetah 2.5.10.6 in my Visual Studio 2013 solution in which I want to create a web role package for deployment. I am using Azure Tools 2.3.
My default web.config transforms are working correctly. However, the SlowCheetah transforms do not work. Somehow this should be working: [Slow Cheetah issue 5](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/5)
In my output window I see the following:

```
1>Task "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml"
1>  Transfroming source file: D:\web\Project\src\Project.Web\App_Config\OTAP\connectionStrings.config
1>  Applying Transform File: App_Config\OTAP\connectionStrings.O.config
1>  Output File: bin\App_Config\OTAP\connectionStrings.config
1>Done executing task "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml".
```

In my bin folder I see the correctly transformed file.

I also see the following line in my output:

```
3>  Task "Message"
3>      TransformedWebFiles = App_Config\OTAP\connectionStrings.config, DestinationRelativePath=App_Config\OTAP\connectionStrings.config, Exclude=False, FromTarget=CollectFilesFromContent, Category=Run, ProjectFileType=Default
```

But when the package is created, the original file is used

```
3>Target "CopyWebRoleFiles" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" from project "D:\web\Project\src\Project\Project.ccproj" (target "CopyRoleFiles" depends on it):
3>  Task "Message"
3>      CurrentRoleWebFiles=D:\web\Project\src\Project.Web\App_Config\OTAP\appSettings.config -> App_Config\OTAP\appSettings.config
3>  Task "Message"
3>      CurrentRoleWebFiles=D:\web\Project\src\Project.Web\App_Config\OTAP\connectionStrings.config -> App_Config\OTAP\connectionStrings.config
```

So my base config is used in the package and I want connectionStrings.*.config to be used.
Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide some version numbers for the products you're working with.

Comment: I've added the question with some version numbers.

Comment: You should file  a bug  with Microsoft for this at http://connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the following MSBuild script:

```
<Target Name="DeploySlowCheetahTransforms" AfterTargets="CopyWebRoleFiles" Condition="'@(WebRoleReferences)' != ''">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <IntermediateWebOutputPath>%(WebRoleReferences.OutputDir)</IntermediateWebOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <TransformedFiles Include="$(WebTargetDir)\**\*.config" Exclude="$(WebTargetDir)\**\*.dll.config;$(WebTargetDir)\**\web*.config" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TransformedFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(TransformedFiles->'$(IntermediateWebOutputPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

This scripts needs to be added to the ccproj file. The `WebRoleReferences` and `WebTargetDir` variables are created in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets. This script gets all the transformed config files from the OutputPath of your csproj file and copies them to the OutputDir which is used to create the Azure WebRole package.